# JQuery Mobile / Rails 4 - Disable Ajax for Forms Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

Past v 1.1 of JQuery Mobile, the ability to turn off AJAX for only form submits was deprecated (it was combined with the global data-ajax setting.)  I am currently working with JQM v 1.3.

Anyone have a quick solution to embed data-ajax-enabled='true' to ALL form tags as they are inserted into the DOM (via JS)?  I've tried numerous ways, but none seem to work.  Please note, adding the data attribute to each individual form tag won't work because several rails helpers (e.g., button_to and destroy) are wrapped into form tags dynamically created at runtime.

Alternatively, if any Rails devs are looking at this, can you point me in the direction of how to monkey patch the form builder class to add the data-ajax-enabled='true' to all form tags?  Also, I request the same help for the other helpers as mentioned above if they don't tie into the form builder object...?

JQuery Mobile is awesome and so is Rails.  Trying to get them to play together nicely is a slight challenge!

Comment: add `data-ajax=false` attribute to form tag.

Comment: @omar - Thanks, I was aware that I could override the setting in each individual form, but I am looking to apply data-ajax='false' to ALL form tags either via JS or by overriding the Form Builder class.

Comment: hmmm..try this `$(document).on('pagecreate', '[data-role=page]', function () { $(this).find('form').each(function () { $(this).attr('data-ajax', 'false'); }); });` I'm not sure if this would work, just give it a try while I think of some other solutions.

Comment: @omar - Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately, no dice!  I've tried inserting the script both before JQM load and after JQM load.  I can't figure out why the JQM team deprecated giving people the ability to toggle AJAX at class levels?

Comment: load it after jQM normally, it's not a global setting. Try it with `pageshow`.

Comment: @omar - thanks again - I actually tried it with pageshow, also.  No go.  I can't figure out why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37677/discussion-between-omar-and-angelo-chrysoulakis)

Comment: @omar - After trying again, it seems that changing the pagecreate to pageshow now works and it submits the form via http.  It only picked up the change after I cleared my browser cache (a little strange...)  I'll mark the answer as correct if you place your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `data-ajax="false"` attribute on `pageshow` to all form tags.

```js
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {
  $(this).find('form').each(function () {
    if(!!$(this).attr('data-ajax')) { // if attribute doesn't exist, add it
      $(this).attr('data-ajax', 'false');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via javascript, which is much cleaner and easier than monkey patching the rails form builder:

```
$(document.body).delegate("form",'submit',function(e){
  $(this).attr("data-ajax", "false");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not work.  Nothing is inserted into the DOM.  I tried it both before JQM is loaded and after JQM is loaded.  Do you have any additional suggestions?

Comment: @AngeloChrysoulakis I have tested it too and it doesn't work for me either. Sorry about that, I thought I had tested it before, but it looks like you found your answer anyway. Thanks for replying about it!